# Technical Analysis to determine optimal Cellular to transmitter location

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication, lte

At a very high level what are required technical analysis to

1. determine the need to for a new 4G LTE cellular transmitter in US?
2. find find the optimal location for the transmitter in US?

**Back Story:** The leading US based cellular service provider wants to install a cellular  transmitter in our neighborhood on public property. The residence are oppose to the idea. In all accounts 4G LTE cellular coverage is very good. Below is coverage map from the vendor.

[image]

The vendor during public hearing claimed that that cellular signals are very poor and shared a some measurement data including Reference Symbol Received Power (RSRP) data for 4G LTE. It appears that the vendor is not upfront of all a facts, only shares selected information.