# How to measure transmit power level from LTE base station?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication, lte

Can someone tell me what type of equipment is used to measure RF power levels transmitted by a cellular LTE base station? I would like to gain some insight into how the follow data was obtained.

[image: Cellular RF power level]

**Back Story:** The local company wants to install a cellular base station in our neighborhood. They have shared the above data set indicating that the cellular coverage is poor in a certain area. But cellular service provider's web site indicate excellent coverage. Information doesn't tally up.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/technical-analysis-to-determine-optimal-cellular-to-transmitter-location

Answer (score 1):

On iPhones the signal strength indicator can be changed to a numerical value as indicated by the image below.

[image]

The above can be done by dialing *3001#12345#*. The phone will enter into field test mode. The value indicated is in dBm. Lower dbm value indicates a poor signal. A dBm value closer to 0 is a strong signal.

Similarly on a Android phone the same infomation can be found at About device -> Status (Kit Kat) depending the Android version.

[image]

**References**

- [Force iPhone to show numerical value for signal strength](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/force-iphone-to-show-numerical-value-for-signal-strength/)
- [Field Test Mode: What it is and How To Enable it on Your Phone](http://www.ubersignal.com/field-test-mode)