# How can one determine the LTE base station providing service to a mobile device?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication, lte

In order to have continuous service a mobile devices switches to base station with higher signal strength.

**Question:** Is it possible using the mobile device (Android or iPhone) to determine to LTE base station to which the device has established a connection?

**Note:** I am interested only for LTE service/devices

Answer (score 3):

You can see this information if you enter "field test mode". Google that for device specific instructions. It should show you the name or serial number of the base station you are connected to, but I'm not sure if you can use that to find it's physical location, although I haven't tried.

Comment: Thank you for the response. wrt "field test mode" is **["How to measure transmit power level from LTE base station?"](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/10914/7083)** what you are referencing